# need help to view PDF using Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm new to **Python** & **Django** . I am trying to make a website for my personal project where you can **upload & view  pdf files** but getting errors . Someone please help me to identify where i need to make corrections.

**This my models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class PDF(models.Model):
    pdffile = models.FileField(upload_to='PDFs/')
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Subject = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Subject
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import PDF


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>This is the Home Page</h1>")

def pdf_view(request, PDF_id):
    a = PDF.objects.get(id=id)
    with open('a.pdf', 'rb') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), contenttype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.pdf'
        return response
    pdf.closed
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from pdfreader import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),

url(r'^(?P<PDF_id>[0-9]+)/$' , views.pdf_view, name='detail' ),
]
```